# I can't edit cells with ng-grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I have this table in **ng-grid**:

```
$scope.data = localStorageService.get('detail');

$scope.gridOptionsdetail = {
    data: 'data',
    displaySelectionCheckbox: false,
    columnDefs: [
        {field: 'order.positions.positionNumber', displayName:'Position',width: 70},
        {field: 'order.supplierNumber', displayName:'Supplier Number',width: 130},
        {field: 'order.positions.salesOrderNumber', displayName:'Sales order Number',width: 155},
        {field: 'order.positions.article.articleName', displayName:'Article Name',width: 180},
        {field: 'order.positions.article.catalogArticleNumber', displayName:'Catalog Article Number',width: 180},
        {field: 'order.positions.article.catalogArticleColor', displayName:'Catalog Article Color',width: 180},
        {field: 'order.positions.article.catalogArticleSize', displayName:'Catalog Article Size',width: 180},
        {field: 'order.positions.article.sapMaterialNumber', displayName:'SAP Material Number',width: 160}
    ]
};
```

As you see i take detailed data from a localstorage and $scope.data caontain this data:

```
[{"order":{"id":132290,"supplierNumber":600301,"catalogName":"CONLEYS","customerNumber":86796929,"orderNumber":132290,"orderDate":"2013-02-06+01:00","orderStatus":"IMPORTED_FROM_SAP","positions":{"id":"132290/positions/10","orderNumber":132290,"positionNumber":10,"salesOrderNumber":654322,"salesOrderPosition":10,"article":{"id":12345679,"catalogName":"CONLEYS","sapMaterialNumber":12345679,"articleName":"CONLEYS BLUE T-Shirt","catalogArticleNumber":6308082,"catalogArticleColor":"Blau","catalogArticleSize":"L"},"orderPrice":"29.90","discountUnit":"PERCENT","orderQuantity":1,"positionStatus":"IMPORTED_FROM_SAP"}},"route":"search","reqParams":null,"parentResource":{"route":"orders","parentResource":null},"restangularCollection":false}].
```

I receive the data correctly in the table but when i add this code:

```
enableCellSelection: true,
enableRowSelection: false,
enableCellEditOnFocus: true,
```

in my **gridOptiondetail**, i can't modify nothing when i click on a cell (or duble click).

There is an other method that can i use for modify data in the cells?

p.s I'm using the version 1.9.0 of ng-grid because with the version up 2.0 i can't see data.

Comment: Here is a Plunker that works with your data: http://plnkr.co/edit/Wo23D4ty3BpZwDHXvK4M?p=preview. I am not sure which version of ng-grid this is, but it shows data and allows editing. Maybe use this as a base to refine your question.